# How can I redirect in JSF 2.0

Tags: jsf, redirect, commandlink

I want to redirect from a link in a JSF page, how can I do it?

In HTML I can use `<a>` tag for this. But in JSF I use `<h:outputLink>` or `<h:commandLink>` as they can be conditionally rendered. I want redirect link to other page in same application or to an external URL. How can I do it with JSF? How can I use `action` in `<h:commandLink>` for this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming that you'd like to redirect to `some.xhtml` which is placed in web root folder:

1. You can just continue using plain HTML.

   ```
    <a href="#{request.contextPath}/some.xhtml">go to some page</a>
   ```

   For conditional rendering, [just wrap it in an `<ui:fragment>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8816212/how-to-conditionally-render-plain-html-elements-like-divs/).

   ---
2. Or use `<h:link>` with implicit navigation.

   ```
    <h:link outcome="/some" value="go to some page" />
   ```

   Note: no need to prepend context path nor to include `FacesServlet` mapping.

   ---
3. Or use `<h:commandLink>` with `?faces-redirect=true`.

   ```
    <h:commandLink action="/some?faces-redirect=true" value="go to some page" />
   ```

   Note: no need to prepend context path nor to include `FacesServlet` mapping.

   ---
4. Or use `<h:outputLink>`, but you need to specify context path.

   ```
    <h:outputLink value="#{request.contextPath}/some.xhtml" value="go to some page" />
   ```

   ---

Redirecting to an external URL is already answered in this duplicate: [Redirect to external URL in JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5092439/redirect-to-external-url-in-jsf/).

#### See also:

- [How to navigate in JSF? How to make URL reflect current page (and not previous one)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15521451/how-to-navigate-in-jsf-how-to-make-url-reflect-current-page-and-not-previous-o)
- [When should I use h:outputLink instead of h:commandLink?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4317684/when-should-i-use-houtputlink-instead-of-hcommandlink)
- [JSF implicit vs. explicit navigation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18037884/jsf-implicit-vs-explicit-navigation)

Comment: Hi Balus thank you, but i have problem with include page, i include menu page into main page and when i click on Register link, it not redirect into register page, can you help me? Thank You ! Best Regards

Comment: The `h:link` outcome must point to the filename of the page without extension and it must be in the same folder as the main page.

Comment: i use h:commandLink, but if menu page in one folder and register page in other folder and i include menu page into main page (it outside all of folder) it can be redirect? in my backing bean if return String outcome i must return such as `return "../register"` ? Thank for your response !

Comment: `UICommand` components should go in a `h:form`. The outcome must just match the page filename. If it's an URL, then you need to define a navigation case in faces-config.xml. You can on the other hand also use `h:outputLink`. This behaves exactly the same as `<a>`.