# When should I use h:outputLink instead of h:commandLink?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

When should I use an `<h:outputLink>` instead of an `<h:commandLink>`?

I understand that a `commandLink` generates an HTTP post; I'm guessing that `outputLink` will generate HTTP gets. That said, most of the [JSF tutorial material](http://www.coreservlets.com/JSF-Tutorial/jsf2/) I've read uses `commandLink` (almost?) exclusively.

Context: I am implementing a wee little demo project that shows a header link to a user page, much like Stack Overflow's...

[image: needs more jquery]

...and I am not sure if `commandLink` (perhaps using `?faces-redirect=true` for bookmarkability) or `outputLink` is the right choice.

Answer (score 203, accepted):

The [`<h:outputLink>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/outputLink.html) renders a fullworthy HTML `<a>` element with the proper URL in the `href` attribute which fires a bookmarkable GET request. It cannot directly invoke a managed bean action method.

```xml
<h:outputLink value="destination.xhtml">link text</h:outputLink>
```

---

The [`<h:commandLink>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.1/docs/vdldocs/facelets/h/commandLink.html) renders a HTML `<a>` element with an `onclick` script which submits a (hidden) POST form and can invoke a managed bean action method. It's also required to be placed inside a `<h:form>`.

```xml
<h:form>
    <h:commandLink value="link text" action="destination" />
</h:form>
```

The `?faces-redirect=true` parameter on the `<h:commandLink>`, which triggers a redirect after the POST (as per the [Post-Redirect-Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) pattern), only improves bookmarkability of the target page when the link is actually clicked (the URL won't be "one behind" anymore), but it doesn't change the `href` of the `<a>` element to be a fullworthy URL. It still remains `#`.

```xml
<h:form>
    <h:commandLink value="link text" action="destination?faces-redirect=true" />
</h:form>
```

---

Since JSF 2.0, there's also the [`<h:link>`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/h/link.html) which can take a view ID (a navigation case outcome) instead of an URL. It will generate a HTML `<a>` element as well with the proper URL in `href`.

```xml
<h:link value="link text" outcome="destination" />
```

---

So, if it's for pure and bookmarkable page-to-page navigation like the SO username link, then use `<h:outputLink>` or `<h:link>`. That's also better for SEO since bots usually doesn't cipher POST forms nor JS code. Also, UX will be improved as the pages are now bookmarkable and the URL is not "one behind" anymore.

When necessary, you can do the preprocessing job in the constructor or `@PostConstruct` of a `@RequestScoped` or `@ViewScoped` `@ManagedBean` which is attached to the destination page in question. You can make use of `@ManagedProperty` or `<f:viewParam>` to set GET parameters as bean properties.

#### See also:

- [ViewParam vs @ManagedProperty(value = "#{param.id}")](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4888942)
- [What can <f:metadata>, <f:viewParam> and <f:viewAction> be used for?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6377798)
- [Bookmarkability via View Parameters feature](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13249844)
- [How to navigate in JSF? How to make URL reflect current page (and not previous one)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15521451)

Comment: I assume that it also doesn't matter if the `<h:outputLink>` is in an `<h:form>` - e.g. it can be, but it doesn't have to be, right?

Comment: No, doesn't have to be. Only [`UICommand`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UICommand.html) components needs to go in an [`UIForm`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIForm.html) component.

Comment: Got it. So - is there any other compelling case to use an `<h:outputLink>` other than pure page-to-page navigation?

Comment: None, actually. Generally, when you can, stick to `h:outputLink` or `h:link` for links. SEO should not be underestimated. By the way, for nice REST-like URL's like here on SO, have a look at [PrettyFaces](http://ocpsoft.com/prettyfaces/).

Comment: Okay, many thanks for the clarification. Is the difference between `h:link` and `h:outputLink` just in the URL encoding (like the difference between `#{...}` and `<h:outputText value="..."/>`)?

Comment: No, the difference is that `h:link` takes JSF view ID (e.g. `page`) as value and `h:outputLink` takes a real URL (e.g. `/page.xhtml` or `/page.jsf`, or other depending on your `FacesServlet` mapping) as value. URL encoding happens anyway in both cases. There's by the way no difference between render behaviour of EL in template text `#{...}` and `h:outputText`. Both escapes predefined XML entities (no, that's not the same as URL encoding). The `h:outputText` only offers more attribtues like `id`, `styleClass`, etc to control the component and/or markup.

Comment: @BalusC What exactly you mean by "fullworthy HTML" in the first line of your answer ?

Comment: @Geek: just to-the-point one HTML `<a>` element, nothing more, no fanciness, no JS code, etc.

Comment: @ethanjyx: that it produces exactly the same result when the current URL in browser's address bar is bookmarked/copypasted/shared/re-executed. I.e. it's idempotent. See further also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15521451/how-to-make-url-reflect-the-current-page-and-not-the-previous-one/

Comment: hey @BalusC, can you please suggest the usages of h:commandLink and h:outputLink in terms of garbage collection? Which should be used so that the memory won't be affected?

Comment: @Asgar: there's no difference at all on that. You should just be using the right tool for the job. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15521451

Comment: @BalusC, I am using primefaces, suppose there are two pages with two different ManagedBeans with ViewScoped, If I use h:outputLink and navigate between them then the PreDestroy method is not called, but if I use h:commandLink then the PreDestroy is called.

Does that not mean using commandLink and navigating or going to different views, the bean is destroyed immediately and is eligible for Garbage Collection? Is it not good in terms of performance?

Comment: @Asgar: outputLink is better wrt performance. In your specific case commandLink is better wrt memory consumption. If you wish these beans to be garbage collected on outputLink as well, use OmniFaces `@ViewScoped` instead of standard JSF one. See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/40569971

Answer (score 3):

I also see that the page loading (performance) takes a long time on using h:commandLink than h:link. h:link is faster compared to h:commandLink

Comment: I find that hard to believe. Aside from hearsay/your own anecdotal evidence, do you have anything to support that?

Comment: @Matt: I can imagine that it's slower when you have a this POST navigation link inside a "God" form in a page with for example a datatable with >1000 rows containing 3 input fields per row. But such a page has other serious problems anyway :)