# Redirect to external URL in JSF

Tags: jsf, redirect, jsf-2, external-url

I've been dealing with a problem with JSF, when it comes to redirect to pages inside my app it works just fine, but I haven't been able to redirect to external URL can some one guide me on this?

Comment: What happens when you try to redirect to an external URL? How are you trying to do it? Show us some code.

Comment: @Matt: I'll bet that he was fiddling with navigation cases and outcome values. That's indeed not possible then. For internal pages a `<redirect/>` or `outcome?faces-redirect=true` works fine.

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Either just mention the URL directly in `<a>` or `<h:outputLink>`.

```
<a href="https://stackoverflow.com">Go to this site!</a>
<!-- or -->
<h:outputLink value="https://stackoverflow.com">Go to this site!</h:outputLink>
```

Or, if you need to to invoke a bean action using `<h:commandLink>` like below,

```
<h:form>
    <h:commandLink value="Go to this site!" action="#{bean.redirect}" />
</h:form>
```

then use [`ExternalContext#redirect()`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/platform/8/apidocs/javax/faces/context/externalcontext#redirect-java.lang.String-) in action method.

```
public void redirect() throws IOException {
    // ...

    ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
    externalContext.redirect("https://stackoverflow.com");
}
```

Note that you don't need to catch that `IOException`, the server will deal with it. Also note the importance of including the scheme (`https://` or `http://` or `//`) in the URL, otherwise it will be interpreted relative to the current domain.

Comment: thanks balus the ExternalContext solution works, proable i was not putting the "http" prefix on my URL, +1 for quickily and certain answer AGAIN