# Send a http post request to external site in JSF application without redirect

Tags: jsf, http-post

I have a JSF application when the user clicks a button, have to do some actions and direct to a JSF new page. The same action must send a request to a sms gateway, where the response it recorded in the application silently, but must not alter any navigation of the JSF pages to user. How can I achieve this functionality?

For example, clicking the save button in report.xhtml page must take the user to new_report.xhtml page, but that click also have to send a http request to an external url and if possible, record the external response.

If I use faces context > request, as in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5092439/jsf-external-site-redirect), it redirects to that external page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always connect to any other site by using [`URLConnection`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/URLConnection.html) as explained here: [Using java.net.URLConnection to fire and handle HTTP requests](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2793150/1065197). If you don't like to have too much boilerplate code, then you may want to use a third party library like [Apache HttpComponents](http://hc.apache.org/) or another library built on top of this one like [Unirest](http://unirest.io/java.html). Using unirest, the code would be very easy:

```
String yourUrl = "http://url.you.want.to/connect/";
HttpResponse<String> stringResponse = Unirest.post(yourUrl)
    .field("parameter1", "parameter1Value")
    .field("parameter2", "parameter2Value")
    .asString();
//retrieving the string content of the response
saveResponseFromExternalSite(stringResponse.getBody());
```

DISCLAIMER: I am not related to unirest library at all. I'm not a developer nor a vendor nor a supporter of this library. I'm just a happy user.