# JSF 2 external redirect and add header while re-directing

Tags: java, http, jsf-2

I found this question [Redirect to external URL in JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5092439/jsf-external-site-redirect/5092509#5092509)
I want to accomplish similar thing, But I also want to add **http header** while redirecting, to be more specific I am getting a request to my JSF application where user enter some information. based on that information I pull out some details from my DB.

Now I need to redirect to another external url(different application) and add some information in Http header which that application can read like key value pairs.

example "userName" "anyuser".

**what is the simple way to do that in JSF 2?**

Comment: It already isn't possible with HTTP, so also not with JSF (which is in the context of this question merely a HTTP controller and HTML generator). If you elaborate the concrete functional requirement for which [you incorrectly thought that this all would be the right solution](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377), then you may have more chance in getting the right solution you're looking for. I *guess* (there are multiple solutions) the missing keyword you're looking for is "SSO". The other possible keyword is "proxy". At least, none of this all is related to JSF.

Comment: Thanks @BalusC for the guidance I might not asking the right question . but i can explain functional requirement. can you guide me in right direction. My JSF App will control the authentication and redirect user to different app which needs to know who the user is? I wants to add a userId(which is common for both Apps) in Http header and do 302 redirect is something similar to SSO. but I don't know how to do it can you please help.