# Not able to put url and actionListener together

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, jsf-2.2, icefaces-3

I am new to JSF and UI.
I want that when I click on submenu my business logic should execute and after that my page get renders. I tried below snippet but its not working, page is getting rendered but `actionListener` is not getting executed. when I remove the `url` part, the `actionListener` is working but now I am stuck like how to render the page.

```
<ace:menuItem id="RedactionCapture" value="Redaction"
    actionListener="#{redactionController.getRedactionList}"
    url="#{firmUtility.legalHoldCreationOrRemovalUrl}"
    style="width:220px" styleClass="dropdownmenu"
    target="imagepgframe">
</ace:menuItem>
```

Answer (score 2):

That is expected behavior. An `actionListener` is a listener for an `action` and not for a URL. You could create an `action` which does a redirect to the URL in combination with the listener or do all the work in the action. Please note that this not only the case in IceFaces, but also in PrimeFaces.

For example (with a listener), XHTML:

```
<ace:menuItem action="#{yourBean.redirect(firmUtility.legalHoldCreationOrRemovalUrl)}"
              actionListener="#{redactionController.getRedactionList}"
              ... />
```

Bean:

```
public void redirect(String url) throws IOException {
    ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
    externalContext.redirect(url);
}
```

See also:

- [Redirect to external URL in JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5092439/redirect-to-external-url-in-jsf)
- [Differences between action and actionListener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3909267/differences-between-action-and-actionlistener)

Comment: Can you please help me with example. How can I do that.

Comment: @AviteshKesharwani I've added an example.

Comment: please accept the answers which solve your problems!