# How to conditionally render plain HTML elements like <div>s?

Tags: html, jsf-2, conditional-rendering

I'm trying to implement a composite component which either displays the information details of a user in plain text or displays them through editable input texts fields if the desired details are those of the user currently connected.

I know that al UI Components can be rendered via the *rendered* attribute but what about the ones which are not UI Components *(for example divs)*

```
<div class = "userDetails" rendered = "#{cc.attrs.value.id != sessionController.authUser.id}">
    Name: #{cc.attrs.value.name}
    Details: #{cc.attrs.value.details}
</div>

<div class = "userDetails" rendered = "#{cc.attrs.value.id == sessionController.authUser.id}">
    <h:form>
        ...
    </h:form>
</div>
```

I know that the div doesn't have the rendered attribute and probably I'm not taknig the right approach at all. I could very easily use an  JSTL tag but I want to avoid that.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

The right JSF component to represent a HTML `<div>` element is the `<h:panelGroup>` with the `layout` attribute set to `block`. So, this should do:

```html
<h:panelGroup layout="block" ... rendered="#{someCondition}">
    ...
</h:panelGroup>
```

Alternatively, wrap it in an `<ui:fragment>`:

```html
<ui:fragment rendered="#{someCondition}">
    <div>
        ...
    </div>
</ui:fragment>
```

Or when you're already on JSF 2.2+, make it a [passthrough element](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/faces/3.0/jakarta-faces-3.0.html#non-normative-feature-overview-3):

```
<div jsf:rendered="#{someCondition}">

</div>
```

Do note that when you'd like to ajax-update a conditionally rendered component, then you should be ajax-updating its parent component instead.

#### See also:

- [Alternative to ui:fragment in JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3713468/alternative-to-uifragment-in-jsf/)
- [Conditional rendering of non-JSF components (plain vanilla HTML and template text)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15946985/conditional-rendering-of-non-jsf-components-plain-vanilla-html-and-template-tex/)
- [Ajax update/render does not work on a component which has rendered attribute](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14790014/ajax-update-render-does-not-work-on-a-component-which-has-rendered-attribute)
- [Why do I need to nest a component with rendered="#{some}" in another component when I want to ajax-update it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9010734/why-do-i-need-to-nest-a-component-with-rendered-some-in-another-component-w)
- [Is it possible to update non-JSF components (plain HTML) with JSF ajax?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13009174/is-it-possible-to-update-non-jsf-components-plain-html-with-jsf-ajax/)

Comment: Thank you! And when it comes to good practices does it make sense to have Composite Components for all these small parts?

Comment: You're welcome. I'd personally use a simple include file. See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6822000/when-to-use-uiinclude-tag-files-composite-components-and-or-custom-componen

Answer (score 12):

This has been easy since JSF 2.2. By using pass-through elements, any HTML element can be converted to a JSF component, which has the rendered attribute.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:jsf="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf">
    <div class="userDetails" jsf:rendered="#{cc.attrs.value.id != sessionController.authUser.id}">
        Name: #{cc.attrs.value.name}
        Details: #{cc.attrs.value.details}
    </div>
</html>
```

Read more at https://jsflive.wordpress.com/2013/08/08/jsf22-html5/#elements

Answer (score 8):

I would just wrap your HTML with `<h:panelGroup>`

```
<h:panelGroup rendered = "#{cc.attrs.value.id != sessionController.authUser.id}">
    <div class = "userDetails">
        Name: #{cc.attrs.value.name}
        Details: #{cc.attrs.value.details}
    </div>
</h:panelGroup>

<h:panelGroup  rendered = "#{cc.attrs.value.id == sessionController.authUser.id}">
    <div class = "userDetails">
        <h:form>
           ...
        </h:form>
    </div>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Another option is to use components from either Seam (`<s:div>`) or Tomahawk (`<t:htmlTag>`) libraries if you already have them in your project.

See: http://www.jsftoolbox.com/documentation/seam/09-TagReference/seam-div.html

```
<s:div styleClass = "userDetails" rendered = "#{cc.attrs.value.id != sessionController.authUser.id}">
    Name: #{cc.attrs.value.name}
    Details: #{cc.attrs.value.details}
</s:div>

<s:div styleClass = "userDetails" rendered = "#{cc.attrs.value.id == sessionController.authUser.id}">
    <h:form>
        ...
    </h:form>
</s:div>
```

Or: http://myfaces.apache.org/tomahawk-project/tomahawk12/tagdoc/t_htmlTag.html

```
<t:htmlTag value="div" styleClass = "userDetails" rendered = "#{cc.attrs.value.id != sessionController.authUser.id}">
    Name: #{cc.attrs.value.name}
    Details: #{cc.attrs.value.details}
</t:htmlTag>

<t:htmlTag value="div" styleClass = "userDetails" rendered = "#{cc.attrs.value.id == sessionController.authUser.id}">
    <h:form>
        ...
    </h:form>
</t:htmlTag>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use another composite components. There are no divs or other additional tags, just exactly the one you need. See this example:

```
<table>
    <tr>...</tr>
    <my:cc rendered="false">
        <tr>...</tr>
    </my:cc>
    <my:cc rendered="true">
        <tr>...</tr>
    </my:cc>
</table>
```

And the my:cc component:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:cc="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/composite">

    <cc:interface>
    </cc:interface>

    <cc:implementation>
        <cc:insertChildren />
    </cc:implementation>
</html>
```

Produces following HTML, no additional tags at all, working with ajax.

```
<table><tr>...</tr><tr>...</tr></table>
```