# Using multiple boolean conditions in EL expression

Tags: jsf, el, or-operator, and-operator

I would like to know how can I combine multiple boolean coniditions in EL.
I have following example and it is not working.

```
<x:someComponent rendered="#{bean.condition1} or #{bean.condition2}">
```

How can I use "OR" and "AND" logical operators in EL?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The operator has to go inside the EL expression, not outside. You should see the `#{...}` as one big scope wherein various variables/conditions interact with each other.

```html
<x:someComponent rendered="#{bean.condition1 or bean.condition2}">
```

#### See also:

- [Our EL wiki page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info)
- [Conditionally displaying JSF components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870462/conditionally-displaying-jsf-components)
- [How to conditionally render plain HTML elements like <div>s?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8816212/how-to-conditionally-render-plain-html-elements-like-divs)

Comment: Thanks.. it work. But i am getting validation error "cannot coerce first boolean argument".

Comment: Apparently it's `null`. You need either to make sure that it's never `null`, or to add a `not empty` or `!= null` check.

Answer (score 1):

The operator OR in an expression EL is ||.

Try this:

```
<ice:panelCollapsible  rendered ="#{mySessionBean.buttonVisibilities['myButton1'] || mySessionBean.buttonVisibilities['myButton2']}">
```

See this tutorial http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/1.4/tutorial/doc/JSPIntro7.html

Regards

Comment: In the very same tutorial which you linked yourself, please read the "Operators" chapter carefully.

Comment: Thanks BalusC.The logic operators in an expression EL: and, &&, or, ||, not, !.