# Conditionally render a <div> based on value of <h:outputText>

Tags: jsf, conditional-rendering

I am using jsf primefaces. I want to display an image depending on the value of a specific outputext. If the text value is 'Alarm *' then a div will appear whith a spesific image. If the value is 'Alarm **' then a div with an other image will appear, etc. I tried the code below but it does not work for me.

```
<h:outputText id="alarmCriticalityValue" value="#{msg[summary.criticality.key]}" />

<c:if test="#{alarmCriticalityValue=='Alarm *'}">
   <div class="alarm1"></div>
</c:if>
```

How should i implement this idea?

Comment: try using rendered attribute instead.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `binding` attribute to put the `UIComponent` instance in the EL scope. The `id` attribute doesn't do that, on contrary to what you expected.

```
<h:outputText binding="#{alarmCriticality}" ... />
```

And then you need to use `UIOutput#getValue()` to obtain its `value` attribute.

```
<c:if test="#{alarmCriticality.value == 'Alarm *'}">
```

That said, you'd better use `rendered` attribute here, particularly if `#{summary}` represents the currently iterated item of a JSF iterating component like `<ui:repeat>` or `<h:dataTable>`.

```
<h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="alarm1"
    rendered="#{alarmCriticality.value == 'Alarm *'}" />
```

#### See also:

- [How does the 'binding' attribute work in JSF? When and how should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14911158/how-does-the-binding-attribute-work-in-jsf-when-and-how-should-it-be-used)
- [How to conditionally render plain HTML elements like <div>s?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8816212/how-to-conditionally-render-plain-html-elements-like-divs)
- [JSTL in JSF2 Facelets... makes sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete problem. It's strange to see the conditional rendering depend on localized text. What if you change the locale and/or the localized text? This is very brittle. You'd better check the bundle key instead.

```
<h:outputText value="#{msg[summary.criticality.key]}" />
<h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="alarm1" 
    rendered="#{summary.criticality.key == 'some.alarm.key'}" />
```

This way you also don't need to bind the output text anymore.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
<c:if test="#{msg[summary.criticality.key].equals('Alarm *')}">
```

Or add a `binding` to the `h:outputText` and check against that.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<h:outputText id="alarmCriticalityValue" value="#{msg[summary.criticality.key]}" />
    <h:panelGroup layout="block" styleClass="alarm1" rendered="#{alarmCriticality.value eq 'Alarm *'}" />
```