# <a jsf:rendered="#{...}"> is not interpreted as passthrough element

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2, rendered-attribute, passthrough-elements

I don't understand why this piece of code is working:

```
<h:link value="Login" rendered="#{sessionBean.userInSessionBean == null}"  />
```

and this piece of code is not working:

```
<a jsf:rendered="#{sessionBean.userInSessionBean == null}">Login</a>
```

Comment: You miss to provide more info as your namespace definitions, used JSF version, browsers you're testing it with...

Comment: @XtremeBiker None of those things have anything to do with it.

Comment: You're right @XtremeBiker. My JSF version is 2.2.12. I've tried on Explorer, Chrome and Firefox. I'm using Prime Faces 5.3 also.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A HTML element will only become a passthrough element if following conditions are met:

1. There's at least one [`jsf:xxx` attribute](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jsf-facelets009.htm#sthref391) from `http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf` namespace.
2. There's at least one "[identifying attribute](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/jsf-facelets009.htm#BABJADGH)" associated with a specific JSF component.

For the `<a>` element an identifying attribute is necessary so JSF can decide whether to interpret it as `<h:commandLink>`, `<h:outputLink>` or `<h:link>`. Without an identifying attribute, JSF wouldn't have any idea what component you actually meant to use, so any `jsf:xxx` attributes will be ignored. The `jsf:rendered` is not sufficient as identifying attribute because it appears on every single JSF component, so JSF would still have no idea which one you meant.

Given that you seem to intend to have a `<h:link>`, then use `jsf:outcome` as identifying attribute.

```
<a jsf:outcome="login" jsf:rendered="#{empty sessionBean.userInSessionBean}">Login</a>
```

A completely different alternative is to wrap plain HTML in an `<ui:fragment rendered>`. See also [How to conditionally render plain HTML elements like <div>s?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8816212/how-to-conditionally-render-plain-html-elements-like-divs)