# Elements with namespace http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html may not have attributes in namespace http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf

Tags: jsf, namespaces

I`m using all the jsf 2.2 new namespaces

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:jsf="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf"
    xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsp/jstl/core">
```

But how much do I try to use component selectOneMenu with selectItem I receive this error:

> HTTP Status 500 - Elements with namespace
>   http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html may not have attributes in namespace
>   http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf. Namespace http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf is
>   intended for otherwise non-JSF-aware markup, such as <input
>   type="text" jsf:id > It is not valid to have <h:commandButton
>   jsf:id="button" />.

This is my selectOneMenu:

```
<h:selectOneMenu class="form-control"
    id="selectOlhos" jsf:value="#{corpoController.corpo.corOlhos}">
        <f:selectItem  itemLabel="Escolha" itemValue=""></f:selectItem>
        <f:selectItem  itemLabel="Verdes Claros" itemValue="Verdes Claros"></f:selectItem>
        <f:selectItem  itemLabel="Verdes Escuros" itemValue="Verdes Escuros"></f:selectItem>
        <f:selectItem  itemLabel="Castanhos Claros" itemValue="Castanhos Claros"></f:selectItem>
        <f:selectItem  itemLabel="Castanhos Escuros" itemValue="Castanhos Escuros"></f:selectItem>  
</h:selectOneMenu>
```

If I remove this component it works perfectly.
Any help?

Comment: Great idea! ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Elements with namespace http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html may not have attributes in namespace http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf. Namespace http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf is intended for otherwise non-JSF-aware markup, such as <input type="text" jsf:id > It is not valid to have <h:commandButton jsf:id="button" />.

The error literally says that you may not use `jsf:xxx` attributes in `<h:xxx>` elements.

I'm not sure how I can explain that more clearly. The error basically says that the `jsf:xxx` attributes should only be used on plain HTML elements such as `<div>`. The `jsfxxx` attribtues are not supported on `<h:xxx>` elements.

In your specific case, this is thus wrong:

```
<h:selectOneMenu ... jsf:value="...">
```

Instead, you must be using:

```
<h:selectOneMenu ... value="...">
```

Or, if you actually want to use the `<h:selectOneMenu>` as a so-called *[passthrough element](https://javaee.github.io/tutorial/jsf-facelets009.html)*, then you should be using plain HTML `<select>` instead.

```
<select ... jsf:value="...">
```

#### See also:

- [<a jsf:rendered="#{...}"> is not interpreted as passthrough element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35637987/a-jsfrendered-is-not-interpreted-as-passthrough-element)
- [Which XML namespace to use with JSF 2.2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31068678/which-xml-namespace-to-use-with-jsf-2-2)