# RichFaces 4.2 Forwarding to a new page with h:commandLink

Tags: java, jsf-2, richfaces

With RichFaces 3.3.3 I was able to use the below code:

```
<h:commandLink action="UPLOAD_PAGE">Upload Document</h:commandLink>
```

The commandLink would take the user to the requested page. However, this code is no longer working in RichFaces 4.2.1, when I click it, it simply stays on the current page. It blinks the screen for a split second as if it was doing something. I see no errors in the logs, or anything, which makes it incredibly hard to debug. Does anybody have any information regarding this?

Comment: What are you using to upload? The `<rich:fileUpload>` has changed in RichFaces 4.

Comment: That link is actually to forward to the upload page. But I am using the default in RichFaces 4 (still being written as we speak).

Comment: Why are you using a command link instead of a normal link? You may find this helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2118656/hcommandlink-hcommandbutton-is-not-being-invoked/2120183#2120183 I can't give a more specific answer as your question doesn't contain the code in SSCCE flavor.

Comment: What was the cause of the problem then?

Comment: I'm using `<h:link`, realized that I didn't need the `<h:commandLink`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have by any chance forgot that navigation rule in your `faces-config.xml` ? and any way you can replace the `UPLOAD_PAGE` with you page name like `action="page2"`

look at this answer if you want to redirect

[How can i redirect in JSF 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3948976/617373)

And also read this :

[Implicit Navigation in JSF 2.0](http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/implicit-navigation-in-jsf-2-0/)