# JSF <h:commandLink> to redirect to a page?

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

I want to click a button "sign up", then it will go to the page 'signup.xhtml'.

```
<h:commandLink action="#{request.contextPath}/faces/signup.xhtml" value="sign up" />
```

I received an error message:

```
/index.xhtml @25,90 action="#{request.contextPath}/faces/signup.xhtml" Not a Valid Method Expression: #{request.contextPath}/faces/signup.xhtml
```

Edited:
Per suggestion here: [How can I redirect in JSF 2.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3947959/how-can-i-redirect-in-jsf-2-0),

I used this:

```
<h:commandLink action="/signup?faces-redirect=true" value="sign up" />
```

But received another problem:

```
javax.el.PropertyNotWritableException: /index.xhtml @21,33 value="": Illegal Syntax for Set Operation
```

Why does it complain @21 at index.xhtml, and doesn't directly redirect to the page signup.xhtml?

Comment: Try with action="signup"

Comment: The same thing. It seems it doesn't allow #{request.contextPath}/faces/ part.